# Retornar valores En Función

Tags: javascript, funciones

Hola tengo el siguiente código y me gustaría que al ejecutar main me muestre el resultado de las dos funciones que contiene.

```
function main(){

sumar()
restar() 

}

function sumar() {
return a+b;
  
}

function restar() {
return a-b;
  
}
a=10;
b=5
resultado = main()
console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Primera Solución

> al ejecutar `main` me muestre el resultado de las dos funciones que contiene.

Una de las formas de mostrar el resultado de las 2 funciones que "contiene" puede ser la siguiente:

```js
var a=10;
var b=5

function main(){ // creo un objeto en donde almaceno el valor que devuelve la funcion sumar y restar, y devuelvo el objeto
  resultado = {};
  resultado.suma = sumar();
  resultado.resta = restar();
  return resultado;
}

function sumar() {
  return a+b;
}

function restar() {
  return a-b;  
}

resultado = main();
console.log(resultado);
```

---

Ahora bien, hay cosas en tu pregunta y en tu código que no quedan muy claras.

Lo primero:

> al ejecutar main me muestre el resultado de las dos funciones que contiene.

Lo de que `main` "contiene" 2 funciones se me hace un poco raro de leer, podemos decir que la función `main` ejecuta 2 funciones.

Hablo de ejecutar, porque noto que quizás tengas algunas dudas con respecto a lo que puede devolver una función.

En javascript una [función](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) puede, o devolver 1 valor o no devolver nada.

En el caso de el código de tu pregunta:

```js
function main(){ // main no devuelve nada (no hay un "return")
  sumar()
  restar()
}

function sumar() {
 return a+b; 
}

function restar() {
 return a-b; 
}
a=10;
b=5
resultado = main()
console.log(resultado);
```

Puedes notar que si lo ejecutas obtienes en la consola `undefined`, esto es porque la función `main()` no devuelve ningún valor, por ende, javascript le asigna a la variable `resultado` el "valor" `undefined`.

Tu pregunta es un poco confusa porque, como dijimos anteriormente, una funcion puede devolver 1 solo valor.

Por lo tanto, cuando dices:

> al ejecutar `main` me muestre el resultado de las dos funciones que contiene.

Estás hablando de el resultado de ejecutar 2 funciones, es decir 2 valores. Aquí es donde debes decidir qué devolverá la función `main`.

La solución planteada al principio utiliza un objeto que contiene los resultados de ambas funciones, y luego devuelve dicho objeto.

Si bien en la solución estamos devolviendo el resultado de 2 funciones, lo hacemos dentro de un objeto, por lo tanto, estamos respetando el hecho de que una función devuelva 1 solo valor (en este caso, 1 objeto).

---

### Consejos

Te dejo algunos consejos para que el código sea un poco mas reutilizable y/o quizás mas claro:

```js
function main(a,b){ // En vez de declarar las variables a y b de forma global las recibimos como parámetros
  return {
    suma: sumar(a,b),
    resta: restar(a,b)
  }; 
}

function sumar(a,b) { // Lo mismo aquí
 return a+b; 
}

function restar(a,b) { // Lo mismo aquí
 return a-b; 
}

let a=10;
let b=5;
resultado = main(a,b); // Envío las variables a y b como parámetros
console.log(resultado);
```

Al usar parámetros, ahora las funciones `main`, `sumar` y `restar` pueden ser utilizadas con otros parámetros y no dependen de una variable global.

Esto sería:

```js
function main(a,b){ // En vez de declarar las variables a y b de forma global las recibimos como parámetros
  return {
    suma: sumar(a,b),
    resta: restar(a,b)
  }; 
}

function sumar(a,b) { // Lo mismo aquí
 return a+b; 
}

function restar(a,b) { // Lo mismo aquí
 return a-b; 
}

console.log("Sumar -> ", sumar(5,12));
console.log("Restar -> ", restar(20,8));
/*Etc*/
```

Comment: Genial gracias chicos por ayudarme , me ha resultado muy útil la forma en la que habéis resuelto mi duda, me a gustado mucho la forma de refactorizar el código de Andrés gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya resultado útil. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha solucionado tu problema. Saludos!